# Database backup without Replication objects (for schema comparison purpose)

Tags: sql-server, backup, replication

I want to perform a schema comparison between an attached database and a backup. The backup comes from a replicated database. The comparison (database -> backup) result script generates delete of replication objects, and that's what I want to avoid.

Is there a way to perform a backup without replication objects ?

Comment: Why do you not just extract the schema and use the tools in visual studio do to schema comparisons?

Comment: You're right. The problem is that the server is out of my control and I have only the possibility to run some specific queries. I'll try to ask them (owner) for a schema script. Thanks

Comment: @TomTom I have finally received schema script..Now I don't know how to make end to this question.